# Update descomplicado

Tags: sql-update

Olá uma boa noite a todos primeiramente, minha duvida é a seguinte...
no meu site eu tenho um sistema de visitas ele funciona da seguinte maneira

se( nao existir a sessao visita){

$pega = "pega os campos da visita no banco";

$array = mysqli fetch array na cariavel pega

$visita = $array['nome do campo'] + 1;

$altera = da um update no campo visitas com a variavel visita

define a sessao visita abaixo
}

minha duvida é a seguinte, não teria alguma forma de estar fazendo um update mais descomplicado ? ex:

$visita = update visitas set visitas + 1

algo assim do tipo entendem ? com apenas uma query já amenta um numero a mais no meu contador de visitas, sem precisa recuparar os campos fazer um fetch array e so depois o update, agradeço deis de já pela ajuda, feliz ano novo a todos vocês !!

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que me parece vc só quer incrementar um na variavel visitas, então seria:

```
UPDATE table_name SET visitas = (visitas + 1) WHERE condicao
```